# Tracking ajax request status in a Flux application

Tags: reactjs-flux

We're refactoring a large Backbone application to use Flux to help solve some tight coupling and event / data flow issues. However, we haven't yet figured out how to handle cases where we need to know the status of a specific ajax request

When a controller component requests some data from a flux store, and that data has not yet been loaded, we trigger an ajax request to fetch the data. We dispatch one action when the request is initiated, and another on success or failure.

This is sufficient to load the correct data, and update the stores once the data has been loaded. But, we have some cases where we need to know whether a certain ajax request is pending or completed - sometimes just to display a spinner in one or more views, or sometimes to block other actions until the data is loaded.

Are there any patterns that people are using for this sort of behavior in flux/react apps? here are a few approaches I've considered:

1. Have a 'request status' store that knows whether there is a pending, completed, or failed request of any type. This works well for simple cases like 'is there a pending request for workout data', but becomes complicated if we want to get more granular 'is there a pending request for workout id 123'
2. Have all of the stores track whether the relevant data requests are pending or not, and return that status data as part of the store api - i.e. WorkoutStore.getWorkout would return something like { status: 'pending', data: {} }.  The problem with this approach is that it seems like this sort of state shouldn't be mixed in with the domain data as it's really a separate concern. Also, now every consumer of the workout store api needs to handle this 'response with status' instead of just the relevant domain data
3. Ignore request status - either the data is there and the controller/view act on it, or the data isn't there and the controller/view don't act on it. Simpler, but probably not sufficient for our purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solutions to this problem vary quite a bit based on the needs of the application, and I can't say that I know of a one-size-fits-all solution.

Often, #3 is fine, and your React components simply decide whether to show a spinner based on whether a prop is null.

When you need better tracking of requests, you may need this tracking at the level of the request itself, or you might instead need this at the level of the data that is being updated.  These are two different needs that require similar, but slightly different approaches.  Both solutions use a client-side id to track the request, like you have described in #1.

If the component that calls the action creator needs to know the state of the request, you create a requestID and hang on to that in this.state.  Later, the component will examine a collection of requests passed down through props to see if the requestID is present as a key.  If so, it can read the request status there, and clear the state.  A RequestStore sounds like a fine place to store and manage that state.

However, if you need to know the status of the request at the level of a particular record, one way to manage this is to have your records in the store hold on to both a clientID and a more canonical (server-side) id.  This way you can create the clientID as part of an optimistic update, and when the response comes back from the server, you can clear the clientID.

Another solution that we've been using on a few projects at Facebook is to create an action queue as an adjunct to the store.  The action queue is a second storage area.  All of your getters draw from both the store itself and the data in the action queue.  So your optimistic updates don't actually update the store until the response comes back from the server.

Comment: thanks - we ended up going with sort of a hybrid of options #1 and #2. Our api layer handles all api requests and data caching, and any request to the api layer for data returns a response that includes the data and the ajax request status. In the stores, if we need to track something about the status of a particular request, we save it as part of the store state with a more meaningful name.